# Algorighm or design pattern for efficient, random-access Cumulative Sum

Tags: language-agnostic, processing-efficiency, cumulative-sum

I am tinkering with geospatial data, specifically Tracks (ordered sequences of geographic positions defined by latitude and longitude).

Most applications require that I calculate the cumulative distance from start to a given point. So, if I call `track.totalDistance[20]`, for example, I would get the distance from start to the point with index 20.

Currently I am solving this by pre-calculating every consecutive distance, increasing a variable, and assigning the value to each point, which is not a good behavior because I plan to edit the track (add, delete and update points), and "total distance" is not actually an intrinsic property of a trackpoint, but of a trackpoint in the context of its containing track.

On the other hand, if I defer evaluation for a getter function, say, `getTotalDistance(track, 20)`, there would be a lot of repetitive and actually unnecessary calculations.

So the question is: How could I implement a class in a way that I could more efficiently get the cumulative sum of an arbitrary index at any time, while avoiding unnecessary computations (full initialization or repetitive)?

Languages that I use are mostly Python, Javascript and C#, but I suppose the answer could be a general structure that could be implemented in any language.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self-balancing tree, with nodes like this:

```cs
public class Node
{
    public Node(Node leftChild, Node rightChild)
    {
        FirstPoint = leftChild.FirstPoint;
        LastPoint = rightChild.LastPoint;
        LeafCount = leftChild.LeafCount + rightChild.LeafCount;
        BetweenDistance = leftChild.LastPoint.DistanceTo(rightChild.FirstPoint);
        TotalDistanceSum = leftChild.TotalDistanceSum
            + BetweenDistance
            + rightChild.TotalDistanceSum;
        IsLeaf = false;
        LeftChild = leftChild;
        RightChild = rightChild;
    }

    public Node(Point p)
    {
        FirstPoint = p;
        LastPoint = p;
        LeafCount = 1;
        IsLeaf = true;
    }

    /// The point of the leftmost decendant.
    public Point FirstPoint { get; set; }
    /// The point of the rightmost decendant.
    public Point LastPoint { get; set; }

    /// Number of leaves.
    public int LeafCount { get; set; }
    /// The distance from FirstPoint to LastPoint along the path.
    public double TotalDistanceSum { get; set; }
    /// The distance between LeftChild and RightChild.
    public double BetweenDistance { get; set; }

    /// Flag wheter this is a node or a leaf.
    public bool IsLeaf { get; set; }
    /// Left child of this non-leaf node.
    public Node LeftChild { get; set; }
    /// Right child of this non-leaf node.
    public Node RightChild { get; set; }

    /// Calculates the distance between two point along the path. 'start' is inclusive. 'end' is exclusive.
    public double DistanceSum(int start, int end)
    {
        if (IsLeaf || start >= LeafCount || end < 0 || start >= end)
            return 0;

        if (end > LeafCount) end = LeafCount;
        if (start < 0) start = 0;

        if (start == 0 && end == LeafCount)
            return TotalDistanceSum;

        int n = LeftChild.LeafCount;
        return LeftChild.DistanceSum(start, end)
            + BetweenDistance
            + RightChild.DistanceSum(start - n, end - n);
    }
}

public class Point
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public double DistanceTo(Point other)
    {
        double dx = other.X - X;
        double dy = other.Y - Y;
        return Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```cs
var tree = new Node(
    new Node(
        new Node(new Point(0,0)),
        new Node(new Point(1,0))
    ),
    new Node(
        new Node(new Point(1,1)),
        new Node(new Point(0,1))
    )
);
double dist = tree.DistanceSum(0,4); // returns 3.0
```

Comment: While this seems pretty ingenious, it's a bit too advanced for me now... I'll have to take a look at this for a while, but the words "self balancing tree" sound like what I imagine to be the best way to go in geospatial stuff like these (along with K-D-trees of course). Thank you for now!

Comment: The self-balancing is only to ensure there is a worst-case O(log n) time for each operation. If the tree gets tilted into a linked list, it will make the operations take worst-case O(n) time. It will work fine without the self-balancing, but not always as effectively.

Comment: Without self-balancing, you could recursively create a tree from each half of the nodes, and combine them into one tree. That will give you an initial balanced tree. Over time the tree probably will get skewed though.